# How would 'sub-recipe' data best be related to the 'recipe' table in this ERD/Database schema?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, erd

I have a junction table that ties products to ingredients to represent recipes.

I intend to allow users to use "sub-recipes", which would mean you can include one recipe inside of another. Logically, this shakes down to mean that in the front-end, when you add a "sub-recipe" to a recipe, then in the back-end you just create an entry in `product_has_ingredient` tying each of the ingredients related to the sub-recipe product to the new product.

However, this does not maintain the idea that the relationship is distinct from normal ingredients. I am trying to come up with a way to allow a product to optionally have a sub-recipe that maintains the same functional structure as what I have now:

[image: Relevant portion of database ERD showing four related tables]

Answer (score 1):

Your receipe looks like a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials) since it only decomposes the ingredients without providing the instructions on how the ingredients are used. Moreover, the receipe is not identified on its own, since it's only the association between a product and its ingredients.

A sub-receipe could be factored into such a structure by one of the following approaches:

1. Identify the  sub-receipe in `product_has_ingredient`. Such an identifier can be as simple as a flag (on sub-receipe only), a chronological step number (1, 2, ... n) or some kind of group plaintext grouping identifier. If needed,  you could add a weak entity to identify a product's sub-receipe.
2. Manage the sub-receipe as a pseudo-ingredient that refers to a semi-finished product.  This means that `ingredient` could have a one-to-one relation with a `product`  (i.e. "corresponds") and `product` would have a flag `is_semi_finished`.

The alternative 1 would work as it is, with the possibility to identify sub-receipes.  The alternative 2 needs more work, since you would not see the sall the ingredients at once, but you would first have to explode that BOM,  iteragting over ingredients and replace it with its own ingredients whenever it corresponds to a (semi-finished) product.

There are many other possible approaches, but these two seem the closest to your current structure.  A more ambitious way would be to refactor  `receipe` as a strong entity, related to itself (sub-receipe), and associate products to receipes and receipes to ingredients and instructions.

Comment: Thanks Christophe. After some thought I've decided that for the MVP I will use an implementation like your second suggestion, but simplified - I will create an option to save a product as an ingredient, basically wrapping up its cost into a package that can then be used in other products as an ingredient. Since the ingredient is then also saved as its own product, the user could edit that product in the future and overwrite the ingredient or create a new one based on modifications.